# Duplicate rows after a MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

___Rooms

```
|--------|------------|
| ROO_Id | ROO_Number |
|--------|------------|
| 1      | 101        |
| 2      | 102        |
| 3      | 103        |
| 4      | 104        |
| 5      | 105        |
|--------|------------|
```

___Bookings

```
|--------|------------|------------|------------|-------------------|
| BOO_Id | BOO_RoomId | BOO_DateCI | BOO_DateCO | BOO_ArrivalStatus |
|--------|------------|------------|------------|-------------------|
| 1      | 1          | 2018-07-03 | 2018-07-05 | checkout          |
| 2      | 2          | 2018-07-16 | 2018-07-17 | checkin           |
| 3      | 3          | 2018-07-14 | 2018-07-16 | none              | 
| 4      | 5          | 2018-07-14 | 2018-07-18 | checkin           | 
|--------|------------|------------|------------|-------------------|
```

---

My goal is to have the following report:

> The date of the report is today : `2018-07-16`.

```
|------------|----------------|-------------------|
| ROO_Number | BOO_LiveStatus | BOO_ArrivalStatus |
|------------|----------------|-------------------|
| 101        | no             | checkout          |
| 102        | in-house       | checkin           |
| 103        | in-house       | none              |
| 104        | no             | 0                 |
| 105        | in-house       | checkin           |
|------------|----------------|-------------------|
```

---

I put a SQLFidde here :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/854079/5

---

Actually, I'm very near but I have a little problem.

In my report I need one row per room in ___Rooms table. But actually, I have more rows (2 for #102).

`(1, 2, '2018-07-13', '2018-07-15', 'checkout')` should not be display because the today date is not between 2018-07-13 and 2018-07-15.

---

My last try was this one:

```
SELECT 
    ROO_Number, 
    IF(BOO_DateCI <= '2018-07-16' AND BOO_DateCO >= '2018-07-16', 'in-house', 'no')
        AS BOO_LiveStatus,
    IFNULL(BOO_ArrivalStatus, '0') 
        AS BOO_ArrivalStatus
FROM ___Rooms
LEFT JOIN ___Bookings
    ON ___Rooms.ROO_id = ___Bookings.BOO_RoomId
ORDER BY ROO_Number
```

Could you please help me please ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You state `(1, 2, '2018-07-13', '2018-07-15', 'checkout') should not be display because the today date is not between 2018-07-13 and 2018-07-15.` but you have no WHERE clause to filter this out.

Comment: You have no `WHERE` clause.  `WHERE` is where you filter records.  Add the clause, and it should resolve your problem.

Comment: Hello @fyroc, this line is not supposed to do this filter: `IF(BOO_DateCI <= '2018-07-16' AND BOO_DateCO >= '2018-07-16', 'in-house', 'no') AS BOO_LiveStatus` ? Sorry for my question.

Comment: @user10065337 you need a where clause similar to this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/854079/30/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the date check to the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT 
    ROO_Number, 
    IF(BOO_DateCI <= '2018-07-16' AND BOO_DateCO >= '2018-07-16', 'in-house', 'no')
        AS BOO_LiveStatus,
    IFNULL(BOO_ArrivalStatus, '0') 
        AS BOO_ArrivalStatus
FROM ___Rooms
LEFT JOIN ___Bookings
    ON ___Rooms.ROO_id = ___Bookings.BOO_RoomId 
        AND CURDATE() BETWEEN ___Bookings.BOO_DateCI AND ___Bookings.BOO_DateCO
ORDER BY 
  ROO_Number
```

You need to do it in `ON` rather than `WHERE` because putting it in `WHERE` will filter out all the rooms with no bookings at all (since the columns will be `NULL`).

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/854079/28)

Comment: Give me a moment to fully test your answer. Thanks in advance.